# Regex for alphanumeric 7 characters, require one digit

Tags: regex, vba

I need a pattern for a seven-digit alphanumeric text the letters must be capitalized and seven upper-case characters must not be possible so there must always be at least one number in the seven-digit text.

Correct examples would be

```
1234568
AB45687
```

Not correct:

```
a456757
ABCDEFG
```

Actually I'm here: `\b[A-Z0-9]{7}\b`

Unfortunately, I cannot cover the ABCDEFG case, which should not occur.

I hope you can help me?

Comment: "I need" is the start of many questions which do not demonstrate any own research or own attempts. Please demonstrate that you get at least part of this done yourself. Show the regexes you tried and explain in detail how they failed. Naming the regex flavor you need is necessary. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to understand better what I mean.

Comment: If you discuss own attempts and describe why you are surprised that what you tried did not work and ask about the details of your misunderstandings you might avoid having your question closed as a duplicate of a very generic "How do regexes work?" question.

Comment: Please define which flavor of regex you use. I.e. name the tool evaluating them. This is necessary for knowing whether certain parts of lookarounds are supported or not.

Comment: Hi Yunnosch, im using regix in VBA (Microsoft Excel)

Comment: If it supports lookarounds, you can use `\b(?=[A-Z]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]+\b`

Comment: @User0815 careful, I had forgotten your `{7}` quantifier and it matches longer words than it should

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex relying on a positive lookahead :

```
\b(?=[A-Z]{0,6}[0-9])[A-Z0-9]{7}\b
```

At the start of a word it checks that it can reach a digit after at most 6 uppercase letters. Then it matches 7 letters and digits up to the end of the word.

Comment: Never omit the min value in the limiting (range) quantifier, it is not allowed in some regex engines, or even silently causes unexpected matches.

Answer (score 1):

This should work even if the strings in question are substrings of a larger string:

```
\b(?![A-Z]{7})[A-Z0-9]{7}\b
```

Here we use negative lookahead, i.e., an instruction that `[A-Z0-9]{7}` only matches **if** `[A-Z]{7}` is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for trying to get me to improve my answer.  ;)

Comment: My pleasure. Though I do not see what you mean by "trying". I think I succeeded. ;-)